# Div with text not stretching vertically inside wrapper

Tags: css, html, wrapper

I have a wrapper with inside a header, a left column and the main content.
Outside the wrapper i got the footer.

My problem is that main content, if there's not enough text, doesn't stretch till the bottom of the page. If i insert lorem ipsum etc, being many rows it's all ok, but if i try with only few rows, the main div stops before the very end of the wrapper (or better, the end of the page, before the footer).

Here's my html code

```
<?php session_start();
unset($_SESSION['message']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stili.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/scripts.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header"> 
    <?php
     include('../php/header.php');
    ?>
</div>

<div id="leftcolumn">
<?php
     include('../php/leftcolumn.php');
?>
</div>
<div id="main" >Welcome to our site

...Some text, but not enough to stretch to the end of page...


</div>
         <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer">Copyright 2013</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS

```
html,
body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
min-height:100%;
height:auto;
margin:0 auto -30px;
width:950px;
background-color:#E3AA56;

}

#main {
float:right;
width:680px;
padding:10px;
background:#E0CD90;
text-align:justify;
overflow: auto;

 }

#main a{
font-size:40px;
}

#footer{
 border-top: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
width:950px;
margin:auto ;
height:30px;
background:#ee5;
clear: both;
}
```

Thanks in advice to everyone that will help finding the problem!

Comment: Why give us so many CSS if only a small part matters? ;) It makes it harder for people to help you. Consider minifying your code-sample.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I edited the CSS and left the most important part, main, wrapper, body and footer

Answer (score 0):

Is this how you want it to be like? If not, then please let me know and I'll revise my answer.

UPDATE:-

```
#main {
height:100%
}

#wrapper {
height:100%
}
#leftcolumn {
padding:10px;
height:100%;
}
```

This should work.

UPDATE 2:-

```
#main {
height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
min-height:500px; (you can change this to your liking)
}

#footer {
position:relative;
}
```

This should give you the results you expect. No need to add my previous styling, just use this one now.

Comment: Well, the main div should not be set by default because in theory it may change from page to page. I use this layout not only for the home page, but even for other pages. If i set a height, i will be limited in content i could put there...right?

Comment: Please have a look at my updated answer and change only the things I have specified there :)

Also, the layout remains the same even if you try it out on different resolutions!

Comment: Now setting main height to 100% caused the main div to go over the footer :/

Comment: Thank You for your advices, the last update seems to work pretty well! Thank you very much for your efforts!
Now there's only the problem that my footer will enlarge if i zoom in the page and remain always at the bottom of the page, while i would like it to remain at its place without resizing. You know, like google's footer e.g.

Comment: And I add that now if i add more text, if it's deeper than windows, it will be covered by footer :/

Comment: @Sanci no problem and have a look at my answer now, this should do the trick :)

I added min-height to #wrapper.

Comment: Today i worked all day on it, i managed to change something in better, but not about that damned main div! With your suggestion, even with min-height, if there's too much text, text it's covered by footer. Look at this firefox screenshot http://awesomescreenshot.com/02b19v4k03

Comment: @Sanci I understand what you're trying to say here and that is the reason why I put up _(you can change this to your liking)_ there. So if you have more text, simply change it to a higher value like 800px.

Comment: But i would like it to be elastic and not fixed, in fact i used % and not fixed values :/ I tried with a % but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Splitting a page into multiple columns stretching automatically the height of the viewport is an ongoing topic. Just google for that, there are several CSS based solutions around there.

The problem is, that the height of the surrounding boxes are undefined (html, body, wrapper in your case). You may only add some  "style" if theres a size on the parent as well.

One weired solution is, to set the style of the html object:

```
<html style="overflow:hidden;clip:
             rect(auto);height:100%;;margin:0px;padding:0px;
             background-color:white;">
```

(yes, it's not forbidden, you CAN do that and it's even IE 6 and 7 proven...)
and

```
#wrapper {
min-height:100%;
height:100%';
margin:0 auto -30px;
width:950px;
background-color:#E3AA56;
overflow: hidden; /* not sure if you want that */
}
```

Comment: Well, your advise didn't solve my problem, maybe i explained my problem well.
I would like the main div to go till the end of the page, and not to end with text, leaving blank space under the div and showing the wrapper :/

Answer (score 0):

Here are the **keys** to your problem you should look at and implement however you want:

```
html, body {
height: 100%; 
min-height: 100% /* for firefox */
}

#wrapper, #leftcolumn, #main {
height: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add height in wrapper it will get the height based on the content inside a wrapper :)